# Connect to a MySQL Server using VB6.0

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am trying to set up a centralize database system for my businesses LAN Network.  I have an xampp server set up, and I can connect to it from other computers however when I run the program I am writing I get an error stating that I cannot connect to the server.  Here is the connection code:

conMMS.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=167.25.11.6;port=3306; Database=mms; User=root;Password=XXXX;Option=3;"

What else do I need to do on the server side to allow the program to connect?

Comment: You should add more information for this to be useful. Can you ping the server? Whats the actual error you get? Share some log output maybe with more detail?

Comment: I can ping the server, and I can access mysql trough the browser on the client.  The problem is I cannot connect when I try and access the server through the program I am writing.  I'm using VB6.0 and connecting to the database using the mysql connector.  Everything else on the client works like a charm except when I try to access the server through VB6.0.  The message indicates that I cannot connect to the server.  There is no other information available.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the error I get: